# How Do I use/setup Bootstrap 4's Assets in my project files? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have downloaded bootstrap in my Laravel Project through Composer. I have all the packages in `vendor/twbs/bootstrap/`.

How do I configure bootstrap for use in my php files? I tried with:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="vendor/twbs/boostrap/docs/assets"
```

There I have a question: Something must change/appear in my public folder?

By default it has the following:

Folders:

```
css
  app.config 
js
  app.js
```

Files:

```
.htaccess,
favicon,
index.php,
MyPage.php,
robots.text
web.xml
```

And the bootstrap folder (vendor/twbs/boostrap/docs/assets) has 5 folders.

Answer (score 0):

I imported bootstrap in my app.scss file.

```
// Bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

[See this question on Laracasts using Laravel Mix](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/how-to-use-bootstrap-node-modules?page=1)